# Python - Replacing warnings with a simple message

Tags: python, warnings, suppress

I have built a few off-the-shelf classifiers from `sklearn` and there are some expected scenarios where I know the classifier is bound to perform badly and not predict anything correctly. The sklearn.svm package runs without an error but raises the following warning.

```
~/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1074: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 due to no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
```

I wish to suppress this warning and instead replace with a message to `stdout`, say for instance, `"poor classifier performance"`.

Is there any way to suppress `warnings` in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppressing all warnings is easy with `-Wignore` (see [warning flag docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=isolated#cmdoption-W))

The `warnings` module can do some finer-tuning with filters (ignore just your warning type).

Capturing *just* your warning (assuming there isn't some API in the module to tweak it) and doing something special could be done using the [`warnings.catch_warnings` context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.catch_warnings) and code adapted from ["Testing Warnings"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#testing-warnings):

```
import warnings

class MyWarning(Warning):
    pass

def something():
    warnings.warn("magic warning", MyWarning)

with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
    # Trigger a warning.
    something()
    # Verify some things
    if ((len(w) == 1) 
            and issubclass(w[0].category, MyWarning) 
            and "magic" in str(w[-1].message)):
        print('something magical')
```

Comment: That worked. I decided to capture all the warning that the snippet could generate and report with a generic message. 

`with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
            self.clfObj.fit(self.train_x,self.train_y)
            self.preds = list(self.clfObj.predict(self.test_x))
            self.predProbabs = self.clfObj.predict_proba(self.test_x)[:,1]
            self.evalClassifierPerf()
            if len(w) >= 1:
                print("Poor Classifer detected")`